# What is wrong with this template program?

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I've been trying to learn templates in C++ but I'm getting a little confused with what I'm doing wrong. I was told how to declare friend templates on a FAQ about templates and I had to do that with the overloaded operators but it seems to be giving me trouble telling me I have an invalid amount of arguments(I should have 2) in my Array.cpp. Is there any way I could fix this while keeping my operators. Also, is the simple main file the correct syntax for the templates?

Thank you.

Array.h:

```
#ifndef ARRAY_H
#define ARRAY_H
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T> class Array;
template<typename T> ostream &operator<<( ostream &, const Array<T> & );
template<typename T> istream &operator>>( istream &, Array<T> & );

template< typename T >
class Array
{


    friend ostream &operator<< <> ( ostream &, const Array<T> & );
    friend istream &operator>> <> ( istream &, Array<T> & );

 public:
    Array(  int = 10 ); 

    Array( const Array & ); 

    ~Array();

    int getSize() const; 

    const Array &operator=( const Array & ); 

    bool operator==( const Array & ) const; 


    bool operator!=( const Array &right ) const  
    { 
        return ! ( *this == right ); 
    }


    T &operator[]( T );              


    T operator[]( T ) const;  

 private:

    int size; 

    T *ptr;

};

#endif
```

Array.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib> // exit function prototype
#include "Array.h" // Array class definition
using namespace std;

template< typename T >
Array<T>::Array( int arraySize )
{

    if ( arraySize > 0 )
        size = arraySize;
    else 
        throw invalid_argument( "Array size must be greater than 0" );

    ptr = new T[ size ]; 

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
        ptr[ i ] = 0;

}

template< typename T >
Array<T>::Array( const Array &arrayToCopy ) 
   : size( arrayToCopy.size )
{
    ptr = new T[ size ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
        ptr[ i ] = arrayToCopy.ptr[ i ];
}

template< typename T >
Array<T>::~Array()
{
    delete [] ptr; 
}

template< typename T >
int Array<T>::getSize() const
{
    return size;
}

template< typename T >
const Array<T> &Array<T>::operator=( const Array &right )
{
    if ( &right != this )
        {

            if ( size != right.size )
                {
                    delete [] ptr;
                    size = right.size; 
                    ptr = new T[ size ]; 
                }

            for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
                ptr[ i ] = right.ptr[ i ]; 
        }

    return *this;
}

template< typename T >
bool Array<T>::operator==( const Array &right ) const
{
    if ( size != right.size )
        return false;

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
        if ( ptr[ i ] != right.ptr[ i ] )
            return false; 

   return true; 
}

template< typename T >
T &Array<T>::operator[]( T subscript )
{

    if ( subscript < 0 || subscript >= size )
        throw out_of_range( "Subscript out of range" );

    return ptr[ subscript ];
}

template< typename T >
T Array<T>::operator[]( T subscript ) const
{

    if ( subscript < 0 || subscript >= size )
        throw out_of_range( "Subscript out of range" );

    return ptr[ subscript ]; 
}

// overloaded input operator for class Array;
// inputs values for entire Array

template< typename T >
istream &Array<T>::operator>>( istream &input, Array &a )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < a.size; ++i )
        input >> a.ptr[ i ];

    return input; // enables cin >> x >> y;
} // end function 

// overloaded output operator for class Array
template< typename T> 
ostream &Array<T>::operator<<( ostream &output, const Array &a )
{
    int i;

    // output private ptr-based array 
    for ( i = 0; i < a.size; ++i )
        {
            output << setw( 12 ) << a.ptr[ i ];

            if ( ( i + 1 ) % 4 == 0 ) // 4 numbers per row of output
                output << endl;
        } // end for

    if ( i % 4 != 0 ) // end last line of output
        output << endl;
    return output; // enables cout << x << y;
} // end function operator<<
```

My main file:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Array.h"

using namespace std;


int main()

{

    Array<int> integers1( 7 ); // seven-element Array

    Array<int> integers2; // 10-element Array by default



    // print integers1 size and contents

    cout << "Size of Array integers1 is "

         << integers1.getSize()

         << "\nArray after initialization:\n" << integers1;

}
```

Comment: Please include the error output from your compiler -- your description of what it said is vague.

Comment: What line(s) are you getting errors on?

Comment: Array.cpp:104: error: âstd::istream& Array<T>::operator>>(std::istream&, Array<T>&)â must take exactly one argument
Array.cpp:114: error: âstd::ostream& Array<T>::operator<<(std::ostream&, const Array<T>&)â must take exactly one argument

Comment: Your operator<< is being declared as a member function, not a global. Hence too many arguments (3 including `this`).

Comment: Try removing the `Array<T>::` qualifier from both functions.

Comment: Why are you making `operator<<` and `operator>>` friend of the `Array` class? Every data they need can be obtained with public methods, so there is no real need to break encapsulation here. Moreover, templates and friend declarations often require a bit of reflection ("Do I want all instantiations to be friends or just one? Should it be friend with all the instantiations of the class template, or only when the template paramater is the same? etc. (see [this IBM documentation](http://tinyurl.com/653kmal))). Consequently, I avoid friend declarations when they are not required, like here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the 'Template sources should be in headers' as pointed out by MSN, the lines for your overloaded stream operators in the source file are listed as:

```
template<typename T> istream &Array<T>::operator>>( istream &input, Array &a )
template<typename T>  ostream &Array<T>::operator<<( ostream &output, const Array &a )
```

However, the correct syntax for what you're attempting to accomplish is the one used in your header file:

```
template<typename T> istream &operator>>( istream &input, Array<T> &a )
template<typename T> ostream &operator<<( ostream &output, const Array<T> &a )
```

The declarations in your header file are generally refered to as the non-member stream operators.  However, the ones in your source file are defining a member shift operator, which cannot be used for streaming, and must have only 1 argument.

If you change the declarations to match the header file, it should eliminate your compiler problem.  That said, you will also need to place all of the contents of your source file into your header file or into a separate header which is included at the end of the first.  If you do not, you will get linker errors when you try to create your executable.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting the implementation of your template in a separate file without explicitly instantiating the types you are parameterizing.

In other words, you either need to explicitly instantiate the `Array` template for the types you are using or you need to make the template definition available with the template declaration. I.e., put all that stuff in the .cpp into the header.

Comment: While this is correct, failing to do so would result in linker errors, and it sounds like the OP is getting compiler errors. So I don't think this answers the OP's direct question.

Answer (score 1):

`istream &Array<T>::operator>>( istream &input, Array &a )` shouldn't be in the `Array<T>` class.

With it like that it takes an implicit `this` argument, but you're explicitly passing the array you want in `&a`.

Change that line (and the corresponding `operator<<`, equivalently) to `istream &operator>>(istream &input, Array<T> &a)` and it should compile. This won't mess with other `istream` operators because of function overloading.

Comment: The istream input operator uses a non-const reference to write into, so it shouldn't be const.

Comment: Correct for the `istream`, but the `Array<T>` should be `const` (printing shouldn't modify the thing it's printing).

Comment: `cin >> array` should modify the array. His `operator <<` has a `const Array<T>&` (for printing) and his `operator >>` (for input) has a `Array<T>&`

Comment: You're completely correct. Fixing it now! (Somehow I forgot that `istream` reads, despite your reminder.)

Answer (score 1):

declaration:

```
template<typename T> istream &operator>>( istream &, Array<T> & );
```

definition:

```
istream &Array<T>::operator>>( istream &input, Array &a )
{
```

These should match.  The declaration one is right, btw.  This also applies to the ostream operator